# Casting a Z3 integer expression to a C/C++ int

Tags: c++, api, model, z3

I'm new to Z3 and searched for the answer to my question here and on Google. Unfortunately, I was not successful.

I'm using the Z3 4.0 C/C++ API. I declared an undefined function *d: (Int Int) Int*, added some assertions, and computed a model. So far, that works fine.

Now, I want to extract certain values of the function *d* defined by the model, say *d(0,0)*. The following statement works, but returns an expression rather than the function value, i.e., an integer, of *d(0,0)*.

```
z3::expr args[] = {c.int_val(0), c.int_val(0)};
z3::expr result = m.eval(d(2, args));
```

The check

```
result.is_int();
```

returns *true*.

My (hopefully not too stupid) question is how to cast the returned expression to a C/C++ int?

Help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for a well written first question, you don't see that often! Unfortunately I can't help you so..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Z3_get_numeral_int](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#ga620c6d7e5f7992451bb97743d53afc63) is what you're looking for.

Here is an excerpt from the docummentation:

> ```
> Z3_bool Z3_get_numeral_int(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_ast v, __out int * i)
>
> Similar to Z3_get_numeral_string, but only succeeds if the value can fit in a 
> machine int. Return Z3_TRUE if the call succeeded.
> ```

You should be careful though. Z3's integer is mathematical integer which can easily exceed the range of 32-bit int. In that sense, using [Z3_get_numeral_string](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#ga94617ef18fa7157e1a3f85db625d2f4b) and parsing string to big integer is a better option.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for. And an amazingly fast reply ;-)