# How to convert a variable's value to an int in a model?

Tags: z3

When using a model object, I call `func_decl get_func_decl (unsigned i)` to get the value assigned to a certain function (variable). The problem I am having is taking the output of that (which is a `func_decl`) and converting it to `int`.

For example, if the model is `{x |-> 4, y |-> 12, z |-> 6}`, I would like to get the actual `int` values of those 3 variables (`4`, `12` and `6`).

Comment: You can see this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652069/casting-a-z3-integer-expression-to-a-c-c-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 provides the function `Z3_get_numeral_int` for this purpose:

```
Z3_bool Z3_API Z3_get_numeral_int(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_ast v, __out int* i);
```

Note that the last parameter is a point to an integer that will be filled with the right value if the call succeeds (it will fail for non-numerals or numerals which are not representable as an int).

There are also other functions called `Z3_get_numeral_*` to obtain values of different types, e.g., uint64 etc.

This method works for constants (i.e., func_decls of arity 0). To get the entries of a (non-zero arity) function definition, the following function should be used:

```
Z3_func_entry Z3_API Z3_func_interp_get_entry(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_func_interp f, unsigned i);
```