# obtain the integer from a model after s.get_model()

Tags: c++, z3

In **Z3's C++ API**, I can search for a model by

```
model m = s.get_model();
```

Then:

```
cout << m.eval(A);
```

will give me the value for `A`.

However, `m.eval(A)` returns an expr object but I want to store `A`'s value as an integer in my program. How can I convert an expr to an int?

Comment: You'll probably want to provide an SSCCE or at least show some code if you want help. Without knowing anything about the api you're using... have you tried static_cast<int>(m.eval(a)); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact question has come up before; perhaps these help to clarify: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426861/how-to-convert-a-variables-value-to-an-int-in-a-model/) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652069/casting-a-z3-integer-expression-to-a-c-c-int/)

Answer (score 1):

The C API exposes methods for retrieving integer values from expressions that are integers.
The most general API is:

```
/**
   \brief Return numeral value, as a string of a numeric constant term
   \pre Z3_get_ast_kind(c, a) == Z3_NUMERAL_AST
   def_API('Z3_get_numeral_string', STRING, (_in(CONTEXT), _in(AST)))
*/

Z3_string Z3_API Z3_get_numeral_string(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_ast a);
```

It returns a `string` (`char*`). This allows returning bignums (numerals that don't fit in 64 bits).
Z3 exposes a set of other `Z3_get_numeral` variants for special cases. These are documented in z3_api.h, or see: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/code/group__capi.html

Comment: I am sorry but I can't quite get it. Could you format your code and comments better? I couldn't find Z3_get_numeral_string from the C API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible example using Z3py

```
x= Int('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x + 3 == 5)
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m
y = (m.evaluate(x))
z = y + 4
print simplify(z)
```

Output:

```
sat
[x = 2]
6
```