# Is it possible to force a Z3 model to evaluate boolean expressions involving arrays?

Tags: z3, z3py

Sometimes, evaluating a boolean expression in a model doesn't return a concrete boolean value even when the expression clearly has a concrete value.  I've been able to reduce this to cases involving array expressions such as [this test case](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/K5FB):

```
from z3 import *

x = K(IntSort(), 0)
s = Solver()
s.check()
m = s.model()
print m.evaluate(x == Store(x, 0, 1), model_completion=True)
```

I would expect this to print `False`, but instead it prints `K(Int, 0) == Store(K(Int, 0), 0, 1)`.  Other examples produce similar results.  Replacing the first line with `x = Array('x', IntSort(), IntSort())` gives the same result (though that's up to the default interpretation).  Interestingly, replacing the first line with `x = Store(K(IntSort(), 0), 0, 1)` causes the example to print `True`.

Is there a way to force Z3 to evaluate such expressions to concrete values?

Comment: This may be nontrivial to do as per our comments and your example with temporary model assignments, so your best bet may be to do the equivalent of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652069/casting-a-z3-integer-expression-to-a-c-c-int

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I, too, want to evaluate expressions that contain array equalities, but they are deeply nested expressions, so I can't easily hoist the equality out.

Comment: After thinking about this a bit, I think the issue is that it doesn't make sense to ask the model to evaluate array extensionality (?) statements. So, suppose you want to know whether A==B in a model where A is K(Int, 0) and B is Store(K(Int, 0), 0, 1). What you're asking is, "Is there an index i, such that A[i]!=B[i]? If not, A==B." The index i is implicit, but, I think it essentially turns the evaluation into a satisfiability problem, so, you have to invoke the solver to get the answer.

I think.